# Whether to include individual items or the composite variable in structural equational modelling?

Tags: scales, structural-equation-modeling

I made performing structural equation modelling. Some of my latent variables include a lot of items (e.g.,  20 or more items). Alternatively, I could just include in the model a composite variable based on the items that I have computed myself.

**When performing SEM, is it better to include all the items or just the composite variable?**

Comment: Have you considered a third option called item parcelling? [see here for discussion](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com.au/2009/09/item-parcelling-in-confirmatory-factor.html)

Comment: For example, The original questionnaire have 23-items. When we developed the scale, we hypothesized two factors (general parenting self-efficacy and cultivation of developmental efficacy). I will use only 10-items, which will be under the general parenting self-efficacy factor: And in my Structural equational model, I created a latent variable, naming  general Parenting self-efficacy" and added 10 observed variables (items). But, as you suggested, if I want to do item parcelling, should I find the factors among the 10 items by re-running factor analysis?